# How to use explicit template instantiation to reduce compilation time?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

It was suggested to use explicit template instantiation to reduce compilation time. I am wondering how to do it. For example

```
// a.h
template<typename T> class A {...};
template class A<int>; // explicit template instantiation  to reduce compilation time
```

But in every translation unit where a.h is included, it seems `A<int>` will be compiled. The compilation time is not reduced. How to use explicit template instantiation  to reduce compilation time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know that your template will be used only for certain types,
lets call them T1,T2, you can move implementation to source file,
like normal classes.

```
//foo.hpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    void f();
};

//foo.cpp
template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::f() {}

template class Foo<T1>;
template class Foo<T2>;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the implementation be in the form of `template <typename T> void Foo<T>::f() { }`? Note `Foo<T>::` instead of `Foo::`

Answer (score 19):

Declare the instantiation in the header:

```
extern template class A<int>;
```

and define it in one source file:

```
template class A<int>;
```

Now it will only be instantiated once, not in every translation unit, which might speed things up.

Comment: It will be instantiated in all source files with explicit template instantiation definition directive (`template class A<int>;`).

Comment: @Constructor: Indeed. If you do what the answer says, that will just happen once.

Comment: I only wanted to note that explicit template instantiation *declaration* is not a good protection of multiple instantiations of a template (accidental or intentional).

Comment: Could you give a hint at good protection for that? Is there any at all? I typically use 2 header files -- the one which holds the template code, the other which includes the first and only contains the "extern template" explicit specilization declarations. A source file then includes the first one and does the explicit declaration and all other source files include the second with the "extern template" declarations.