# C++: Parallelize Template Instantiation

Tags: c++, c++17, template-instantiation

We have a big class with multiple template parameters. To cut down on compile time, we are already using [explicit instantiatiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247711/how-to-use-explicit-template-instantiation-to-reduce-compilation-time). While this reduces the compile time of everyone who includes the header, compiling the cpp file is still super slow.

Is there any way to tell the compiler (here: gcc and clang) to instantiate multiple templates in parallel?

We would like to have the same effect as putting `template class Foo<T1>;` and `template class Foo<T2>;` from the linked question into two different cpp files.

Since there are multiple cases of `Foo` and multiple different instantiations, having to maintain a file for each is not optimal. Also, the explicit instantiation as seen above is generated by a macro.

Comment: Yes put your explicit instantiations into separate compilation units.

Comment: That^ and use parallel compilation

Comment: I added the last paragraph to the question. Since there are many `Foo`s and `T`s (which are generated by meta-programming magic), having to generate the files by hand is really ugly.

Comment: Is this file changing frequently? Otherwise, using ccache or some build system that caches build artifacts can speed up subsequent compilations.

Comment: Yepp, ccache is already doing its magic. Even then, we can't avoid changes to that file. Having to avoid that file is a bad idea in my experience, because it leads people to use ugly hacks where they don't have to touch that file.