# How to generate a list of implicit template instantiations to subsequently reduce compilation time?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang

In the codebase I'm working with there are a lot of implicit instantiations of variadic templates like this:

```
template <typename...Types>
void function(std::tuple<Types...> t);
```

[Explicit template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26247805/8414561) is reported to help reduce compilation time.

Is it possible to automatically generate a list of all `function` template instantiations to store them in a dedicated header+source pair to reduce time of subsequent compilation?

Comment: what do you mean by "automatically"? the information what instantiations you need later has to come from somewhere

Comment: @user463035818 as in I build the codebase in regular mode and somehow extract this list from object files.

Comment: You can list the symbols in the object files in demangled form and then search that for constructors like `::MyTemplate<`. This is all platform specific so that information would help form a more precise answer.